# Java working with .class

Tags: java, class, generics

I am creating java app which will allow storing objects in database. What I want to do is generic implementation so it could load json and create java class from it. This is what a code should look like:

```
SomeClass someObject= data.getValue(SomeClass.class);
```

Lets say that data would be a json object. How should I implement `getValue()` method so it will allow me to create class from it. I don't want `SomeClass` to extend anything other then `Object`. I think that this should be done using generic classes but so far I have not worked with generic classes like this. Can you please point to a best way on how to acomplish this? Example code would be best.

Many thanks

Comment: You may use generics to have a generic return type but you have to use reflection classes to create an instance and populate it by reflection.

Comment: Haven't heard of them till now. Will definetly look into this, thanks

Comment: Well. And you could also directly use gson or Jackson lib that provide this feature.

Comment: @davidxxx: Which is a much safer and more robust solution, no?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels  Sure of sure :)

Comment: Yes I can use gson but I wanted to learn how this is dones if I want to implement it on my own type of objects which could not be json all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consult the source code of Jackson library and look inside (or debug) the method [BeanDeserializer#vanillaDeserialize()](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializer.java#L272), there you'll find the loop which traverse through all json tokens, finds the corresponding fields and sets their values.

As a proof of concept, I've extracted part of the logic from Jacskson and wrapped it inside a naive (and fragile) object mapper and a naive (and fragile) json parser:

```
public static class NaiveObjectMapper {
  private Map<String, Object> fieldsAndMethods;
  private NaiveJsonParser parser;

  public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType) {
    parser = new NaiveJsonParser(content);

    try {
      // aggregate all value type fields and methods inside a map
     fieldsAndMethods = new HashMap<>();
      for (Field field : valueType.getDeclaredFields()) {
        fieldsAndMethods.put(field.getName(), field);
      }
      for (Method method : valueType.getMethods()) {
        fieldsAndMethods.put(method.getName(), method);
      }

      // create an instance of value type by calling its default constructor
      Constructor<T> constructor = valueType.getConstructor();
     Object bean = constructor.newInstance(new Object[0]);

      // loop through all json nodes
      String propName;
      while ((propName = parser.nextFieldName()) != null) {
        // find the corresponding field
        Field prop = (Field) fieldsAndMethods.get(propName);
        // get and set field value
        deserializeAndSet(prop, bean);
      }
      return (T) bean;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }

  private void deserializeAndSet(Field prop, Object bean) {
    Class<?> propType = prop.getType();
    Method setter = (Method) fieldsAndMethods.get(getFieldSetterName(prop));
    try {
      if (propType.isPrimitive()) {
        if (propType.getName().equals("int")) {
          setter.invoke(bean, parser.getIntValue());
        }
      } else if (propType == String.class) {
        setter.invoke(bean, parser.getTextValue());
      }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private String getFieldSetterName(Field prop) {
    String propName = prop.getName();
    return "set" + propName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propName.substring(1);
  }
}

class NaiveJsonParser {
  String[] nodes;
  int currentNodeIdx = -1;
  String currentProperty;
  String currentValueStr;

  public NaiveJsonParser(String content) {
    // split the content into 'property:value' nodes
    nodes = content.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split(",");
 }

  public String nextFieldName() {
    if ((++currentNodeIdx) >= nodes.length) {
      return null;
    }
    String[] propertyAndValue = nodes[currentNodeIdx].split(":");
    currentProperty = propertyAndValue[0].replace("\"", "").trim();
    currentValueStr = propertyAndValue[1].replace("\"", "").trim();
    return currentProperty;
  }

  public String getTextValue() {
    return String.valueOf(currentValueStr);
  }

  public int getIntValue() {
    return Integer.valueOf(currentValueStr).intValue();
  }
}

public static class User {
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "id = " + id + ", name = \"" + name + "\"";
  }
}
```

To see the deserialization in action run:

```
String json = "{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"jsmith\"}";
NaiveObjectMapper objectMapper = new NaiveObjectMapper();
User user = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);
System.out.println(user);
```

Or try [online](https://ideone.com/v3ZuUZ).

However I recommend not to reinvent the wheel and use Jackson and in case you need some custom actions you can use custom deserialization, see [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson).